# Dropdown list selection for only specific cell ranges in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, list

I'm trying to have a pop up option come up where a user can select from a list and that is inputted into a cell and the values are separated by commas. I got my VBA code to function but I only want this to be tied to a specific cell ranges rather than the data validation list in basically any cell range.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strList As String
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False

   Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
   On Error GoTo exitHandler

   If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

   If Not Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
      If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then

         strList = Target.Validation.Formula1
         strList = Right(strList, Len(strList) - 1)
         strDVList = strList
         frmDVList.Show
      End If
   End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strSep As String
strSep = ", "
  Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler


Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)



On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else

  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
   If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
   Else
         If oldVal = "" Then
            Target.Value = newVal
         Else
            Target.Value = oldVal & strSep & newVal
         End If
    End If

End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I think I need to update the `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` but when I select a cell range like G1:G100, it causes debug issue.

Also, how can I have the data validation list always show up in Column 'G'?

[image]

Comment: `frmDVList` = Not defined nor set. `strDVList` = Not defined.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Don't know if it'll solve your problem, but you should have a line saying: `Dim strDVList as String, frmDVList as Object` or something. And a line saying something like `Set frmDVList = ...`. Especially when you have `Option Explicit` at the top

Comment: If you want the dropdown list to display when you select a cell in that column you can use sendkeys but that usually toggles numlock as well..  `SendKeys "%{UP}"`

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't really solve my problem..

Comment: I just want it to show up only when a user selects any cell in G. Right now it does that for ALL cells due to the fact that the data validation is set for basically all set ranges in the sheet

Comment: alright so just wrap your code in another if condition, like: `If Target.Column = 7 Then: 'Your code: End If`